# Node.js: Is short route naming SEO friendly?

Tags: node.js, seo

In a SEO point of view, do the following two routes make some differences? Or is a bot smart enough to crawl and index both routes as the landing home page in other views?

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index');
});
```

or

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/index', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index');
});
```

So for SEO purpose, should I use `<a href='/'>...</a>` or `<a href='/index'>...</a>`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center. Read the [tag:seo] tag for why, and where to ask questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index');
});
```

'/' will be your home page or base url

Answer (score 0):

For SEO purposes, `/index` holds no extra value over `/`.  I would just stick with `/` because it's the default expectation of any visitor / bot to find something there when it crawls your domain.

You want to include descriptive keywords in the route when you have specific product / article pages.  For example `/2392-sheep-brushing-widget` is a better route than `/products?id=2392` because it will help search engines provide it as a result for someone searching "widget for brushing my sheep".  However "index" holds no meaning for this purpose.

My rule of thumb is to include (a reasonable amount of) keywords/title in the URL and try to exclude as much of the non-keyword crud as possible.  For example `/webapp/store/v2.3/products/details/2392` is a very poor URL that holds no value to a search engine or human.